# using nginx to serve multiple apps from unique IPs

Tags: node.js, nginx, vps

I've got two IPs associated with my VPS, and am trying to set this up to serve two node apps. Here's my configuration:

In /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain1:

```
upstream app_domain1 {
        server 127.0.0.1:4000;
}

server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name IP1.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.log;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Nninx-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://app_domain1/;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

And in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain2

```
upstream app_domain2 {
        server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
        listen 0.0.0.0:80;
        server_name IP2.xxx.xxx.xxx;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/domain2.log;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Nninx-Proxy true;

                proxy_pass http://app_domain2/;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

And in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, I ran:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1 domain1
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain2 domain2
```

Now, when I go to /var/www/domain1 and run "node app.js" on the correct port, I can visit the relevant IP address and see the app running, but the same is not true for domain2 (I checked that it's running on the correct port for this config. The request just times out - no response at all.

So how can I troubleshoot this?

Update:

If I go to the ports directly, I see both apps available on both IPs, so:

IP1.xxx.xxx.xxx:4000 gives me the app for domain1

IP1.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000 gives me the app for domain2

and

IP2.xxx.xxx.xxx:4000 gives me the app for domain1

IP2.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000 gives me the app for domain2

So it's treating each IP address as the same.

Comment: If you go directly on IP with port 3000, does app2 respond?

Comment: If I do that, I can see the app, but...see update.

Answer (score 0):

<s>`server_name` accepts only domains but not IP addresses.</s>

You have typo mistake in proxy headers, change this:

```
proxy_set_header X-Nninx-Proxy true;
```

with this:

```
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
```

Comment: Ah, so it's not using the server_name at all then. Is there a way to do this with IPs and not domains?

Comment: This resource seems to think that it's ok to use the IP address: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html "If someone makes a request using an IP address instead of a server name, the “Host” request header field will contain the IP address and the request can be handled using the IP address as the server name"

Comment: You need to have two IP's under your control. First IP will be as I assume direct IP address of server, and another will be some other machine with another proxy on it, to do masking instead of redirecting. Then it should work.
As well try to set `listen 80;` without 0.0.0.0 (but should not affect anything anyway).

Comment: Yes, I have the two IP addresses assigned to the server, but I guess my network configuration must be wrong.